# Solving simple linear equation using Matrices

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

I need to find a matrix `A` whose dimensions will be `1 x n` and I have input matrix `X` whose dimensions are `n x m` and another matrix `Y` whose dimensions are `1 x m`.

I have the following equation:

$A * X = Y$

To find `A` we can write the above equation as

$A = Inverse(X) * Y$

right?

But, as `X` is not a square matrix we cannot have its inverse. So, what will be the best possible way to solve `A`?

After a fair bit of research I have found that $X = L * B$ where `L` is the left inverse of `A`. Is this the right approach? If so how to find the left inverse in `R Programming`? I have tried the below code, but `A` and the `PredA` should have same values which they are not.

```
m = 5
n = 10

A = t(matrix(runif(n)))
X = matrix(round(runif(m * n)), nrow = n)

# Y = t(matrix(runif(n)))

# # Usually A * X = Y
Y = A %*% X

library(MASS)
# # Now to find A (Predicted A)
PredA = Y %*% ginv(X)

# # PredA should be equal to A right?
PredA == A # Returns False
```

What could be the basic thing that I'm missing?

I have tried two approaches:

$PredA1 = (X'*Y) * Inv(X*X')$

$PredA2 = Y * Inv(X)$

both resulting in same values (`PredA1 = PredA2`) but none of them are equal to the actual value (`PredA1 not = A`) and (`PredA2 not = A`)

**NOTE:** *I am new to Matrix Algebra. So, I've surely missed something very basic*

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a statistical question but a mathematical one (though possibly involving aspects of numerical analysis or programming). If you can relate it more clearly to a data analysis problem it might potentially be nearer to on topic.

Comment: If considered off topic here, this could be migrated to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General Question**

In general*, if $n<m$ your linear system is over-determined and will not have an exact solution, while if $m<n$ your system is under-determined and will have infinitely many solutions. (*assuming $X$ is full rank, for simplicity.)

In the over-determined case, the typical approach is to find an approximate solution $A$ that minimizes some norm of the residual $||AX-Y||$. For the standard [$L_2$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), this will be the linear least squares solution.

In the under-determined case, there are various approaches, but a simple one is to choose the particular solution $A$ that itself has minimum norm $||A||$. For the $L_2$ case, this corresponds to a [ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ridge-regression/info) solution.

In either $L_2$ case, the solution can be obtained using $X^+$, the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Penrose_inverse#Applications) of $X$.

I do not know how to get this in R, but in Matlab the command is `pinv()`. (Actually, in Matlab the `\` command will solve the system correctly for whatever $m$ and $n$.) Note that numerically, you should really (almost) never explicitly compute an inverse to solve a system of equations. The details of the techniques used in practice (QR,SVD,...) are beyond the scope of this answer, however.

**Specific Code**

Note that in your example, if I understand it correctly the system is under-determined, but you use a "method of manufactured solutions" to get a particular $Y\equiv AX$ based on your pre-chosen $A$. I cannot say if your R syntax is correct.

> However $A_{\mathrm{calc}}\neq A$ would not be surprising in general, due to *[roundoff error](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35796/whats-the-algorithm-for-floating-points-equality-test)*. If this seems strange to you, *please* read that linked answer!

**EDIT:** I answered this pretty late, so was sloppy due to tiredness. (The question may be closed/migrated, but I do not want to put out misinformation, so ...)

Given that your system is *under*-determined, then the "roundoff" comment really would apply more to $||A_{\mathrm{calc}}X-Y||\neq 0$. Given that you appear to generate a random $A$, in the case that your `R` solution is doing the pseudo-inverse method, then the most likely cause of your disagreement is that $A$ includes a component in the [null-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of $X$, which has been changed in $A_{\mathrm{calc}}$ to lower its norm (i.e. in this case you would see $||A_{\mathrm{calc}}||<||A||$).

So you could very well see a "finite" difference in this case.